# Swap Shimano/SRAM freehub for Campagnolo

Tags: shimano, cassette, freewheel, campagnolo, freehub

Through my work I am able to get a set of freewheels pretty cheap (less than 100€). I know they are not super special but they are still an upgrade to my current ones.

Here are the wheels:

https://www.bike-components.de/de/Mavic/Cosmic-Elite-UST-WTS-Laufradsatz-Modell-2018-p57945/
https://www.bike-components.de/de/Fulcrum/Racing-Quattro-LG-Laufradsatz-p44852/

Now the problem is all the wheels I can get are for Shimano/SRAM cassettes but I have a Campagnolo 10-speed. So my questions are:

How difficult is it to change the hub on the new wheels to Campagnolo hubs and would it be possible to just simply swap them out for the freehubs on my current wheels?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Swapping hubs to a complete wheel is almost never practical. You would need a hub that matches the exact drilling of the original hub, or has similar spoke counts if you also replace the spokes. Even spoke counts may be difficult if the wheel has different number of spokes on left and right, as the Fulcrum does.

The good thing is that since these are both third party brands[1] that are marketed for both Shimano and Campagnolo users, you can get just the freehub body for different cassette as spare part for about 50€.

[1] Technically Fulcrum is owned by Campagnolo and the products are mostly the same, just marketed for people who haven't figured out that Shimano compatible wheels have been sold under Campagnolo brand for a long time.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had imagined it would be a hassel but since my budget is very tight it seems like the best option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote you, i upvoted you, but apperently it does not count since my account is very new.

Comment: I guessed so, the downvote and your upvote canceled each other.

Answer (score -1):

The Fulcrum wheel almost certainly has a Compagnolo counterpart, or maybe more than one, as the hub design is likely shared with one or more Compagnolo-specific wheels.  You'd need the Campy freehub, and perhaps a different axle or spacers to effect the swap, depending on the differences between the Shimano and Campy hubs.

The problem is identifying the part(s) needed.  For that, you'd need to dig through the parts diagram(s) for your wheel and then go through the diagrams for the Campy-specific wheels looking for matches.

But it likely can be done.

You're probably completely out of luck trying to get your Mavic wheel to be Campy-compatible short of rebuilding it around a Campy hub.

Comment: Did you try to google for "mavic campagnolo freehub body" before writing that?

Comment: @ojs No, I looked at [the link the OP provided](https://www.bike-components.de/de/Mavic/Cosmic-Elite-UST-WTS-Laufradsatz-Modell-2018-p57945/) and it doesn't show a Campagnolo option.  Did you look there?

Comment: Do you think that the fact that a single retailer does not have Campagnolo option in stock means it does not exist?

Comment: Since I already got the downvote, I give you the answer. Read https://shop.mavic.com/en-fi/cosmic-elite-ust-rr0926.html#1028=3283 and look for words "The hub easily converts". The most probable reason for Campagnolo version not on sale on BC is that it's previous year's model and Campagnolo version has already been sold out.